# In image gallery, images are not adjust properly

Tags: html, css, image

I have some problem with image gallery, I want space right side of image but don't want to change the width of main div because header and footer have same width as main div, So I want image gallery adjust in main div. My code is as below:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="main1">
<div class="content-box-left-bootomgrid">
    <img src="images/etower1.jpg" title="Eiffel Tower - Paris" alt="etower1" width="200" height="200">
    <p>Eiffel Tower - Paris, France</p>
</div>
<div class="content-box-left-bootomgrid">
    <img src="images/W1.jpg" title="Taj Mahal - Agra" alt="Taj Mahal" width="200" height="200">
    <p>Taj Mahal - Agra, India</p>
 </div>
<div class="content-box-left-bootomgrid" style="padding-right:0px;">
    <img src="images/harbour1.jpg" title="Harbour Bridge - Sydney" alt="harbour1" width="200" height="200">
    <p>Harbour Bridge - Sydney, Australia</p>
</div>
<div class="content-box-left-bootomgrid">
    <img src="images/Opera1.jpg" title="Opera House - Sydney" alt="Opera1" width="200" height="200">
    <p>Opera House - Sydney, Australia</p>
</div>
<div class="content-box-left-bootomgrid">
    <img src="images/Twintower1.jpg" title="Twin Towers - Kuala Lumpur" alt="Twintower1" width="200" height="200">
    <p>Twin Towers - Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia</p>
</div>
<div class="content-box-left-bootomgrid" style="padding-right:0px;">
    <img src="images/tower bridge london.jpg" title="Tower Bridge - London"  alt="Tower Bridge_London" width="200" height="200">
    <p>Tower Bridge - London, UK</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.main1{width: 73%; margin: 0 auto;border: 1px solid red;}

.content-box-left-bootomgrid{width:32%;float:left;}

.content-box-left-bootomgrid p{
font-family: Times New Roman, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #000000;
font-size: 0.875em;
padding: 0.5em 0;
line-height: 1.8em;
text-align:center;}

.content-box-left-bootomgrid img{
background:#000000;
padding:6px;
display:block;
width: 96%;
transition: 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: 0.5s ease;
-webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;}

.content-box-left-bootomgrid:hover img{
background:#71D6EA;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `box-sizing: border-box`. It emulates the ie box-model.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: Images are not adjust properly in main div, there is a more space between image and main div at right side..

Comment: oh okay, how about the `:last-child` selector? So doing it like `.content-box-left-bootomgrid:last-child img {...}`

Comment: Not working, actually main div have 73% width and margin is 0 auto. In that in 1st row there is three images, in 2nd there is three images and so on....... the space between third image and main div(right border) is more, space is more

Comment: could you maybe provide a link to your site or a fiddle with - for example - lorempixels? http://lorempixel.com/

Comment: Actually I am learner and working locally, But no worries, Thanks for help.

Comment: No I don't know about it.